# How to disable message "Parameter x is not assigned and could be declared final" in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

I cannot find place in Eclipse preferences where I can disable this message:

> Parameter `pjp` is not assigned and could be declared final

Where are this place?

Comment: That's PMD and not Eclipse. The rule name is `MethodArgumentCouldBeFinal`.

Comment: really) thanks a lot. I disabled it now

Comment: BTW I found that out by googling the warning message.

Comment: strange. I made it too, but maybe it is because I didn't hear about PMD before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your warning message is never produced by Eclipse's built-in checks. It is produced by an Eclipse plug-in called PMD, which supports a much wider range of code checks.

The specific PMD rule name is `MethodArgumentCouldBeFinal`.